# How to rework data in the same SQL table and to erase null values?

Tags: sql, select, merge, null

I have the SQL following structure

| Code | label1 | label2 | label3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| code1 | sth | null | null |
| code1 | null | sth2 | null |
| code1 | sth | null | sth3 |
| code2 | null | word1 | null |
| code2 | word2 | null | null |
| code2 | null | null | word3 |

It is possible to change it using only SQL functions and queries into :

| Code | label1 | label2 | label3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| code1 | sth | sth2 | sth3 |
| code2 | word2 | word1 | word3 |

Comment: GROUP BY, use e.g. MAX().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregate functions like `min` and `max` ignore `null`s, so you could group by the `code` column and aggregate over the rest of them:

```sql
SELECT   code, MAX(label1), MAX(label2), MAX(label3)
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY code
```